# Выборка данных из dataframe с группировкой

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть dataframe такого вида[image: Вид dataframe]

Выполняю группировку по дате

`df = df.groupby('Номенклатура')['Дата'].nlargest(5)`

получаю dataframe вот такого вида [image: Новый df]

Вопрос: Как вывести остальные колонки 'Цена продажи','Цена продажи по акции' и тд?

Comment: Исходные данные (хотя бы часть) в электронном виде приведите. И это не группировка по дате у вас.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему следующим образом

```
cols = ['Дата','Продажи', 'Цена Продажи', 'Цена Продажи по акции']
a = df.groupby('Номенклатура')[cols].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(columns = cols, n = 7)).reset_index(level=0)
```

Comment: Вот тут можно `nlargest(columns = 'Дата', n = 7)`

Answer (score 0):

Можно сначала отсортировать, а потом сгруппировать

```
df.sort_values('Дата', ascending=False).groupby('Номенклатура').head(5)
```

Вот как это работает

```
>>> df
   d  e    f
0  a  1  a-1
1  b  7  b-7
2  b  3  b-3
3  b  2  b-2
4  a  3  a-3
5  a  2  a-2

>>> df.sort_values('e', ascending=False).groupby('d').head(2)
   d  e    f
1  b  7  b-7
2  b  3  b-3
4  a  3  a-3
5  a  2  a-2
```

Можно так

```
>>> df.sort_values(['d','e'], ascending=[1,0]).groupby('d').head(2)
   d  e    f
4  a  3  a-3
5  a  2  a-2
1  b  7  b-7
2  b  3  b-3
```

Comment: а как это отвечает на вопрос? :)

Comment: @strawdog показал

Comment: Вопрос-то был, как вывести остальные колонки. Автор сам на него успешно ответил.

Comment: вот я ему все и вывел :)